# Повторное использование кода React в React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Необходимо реализовать довольной простой сайт на React+Redux. Примерный список функций такой:

Получаем данные с сервера

Выводим списком

По нажатию выводим доп. инфу (в модалке, например)

С таким же точно функционалом требуется и мобильное приложение на React Native.

Т.е. логика приложения будет очень-очень похожая. Данные будут везде одни и те же.

**Вопрос** - как организовать проект так, чтобы по максимуму использовать один и тот же код и для сайта, и для мобильного приложения?

**Мой вариант** - пока что, я пришел к тому, что можно создать каталог "base", в котором будут компоненты и контейнеры, без методов render. В них будут только методы, которые связаны с обработкой данных.

Далее, создаем два каталога, для обеих платформ - web и modile. В этих каталогах создаем одноименные компоненты, наследуя их от компонентов, которые есть в base и реализуем метод render.

Ну и создаем "точки входа" для каждой из платформ.

**Есть вариант лучше?**

Comment: Ваш Вариант прямо в [точку](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам подойдет одна из этих библиотек для кроссплатформенного View-слоя

- https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web
- https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-primitives/